# Codeception `build -c` option removed in 2.2?

Tags: php, automated-tests, codeception

I get an alert. Tests are failing. And not just on my last commit... But on every branch. So something must be wrong with the automated testing. Right?

And here's the message:

```
Failing command: php /var/www/codecept.phar build -c /var/www/protected/tests/ 
Exit code: 1 
Output:                                                      
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The "-c" option does not exist.
```

OK. But it works locally... Hmm... Let's check if I'm running the same version.

I'm not:

```
$ codecept -v
Codeception version 2.1.9
$ wget http://codeception.com/codecept.phar
$ php ./codecept.phar -v
Codeception version 2.2.1
```

So I'm running 2.1.9. And my tests pass. Test continuous environment is getting the latest version 2.2.1. And it fails.

Let's check out the help for 2.1.9:

```
$ codecept help build
Usage:
  build [options]

Options:
  -c, --config[=CONFIG]  Use custom path for config
  -h, --help             Display this help message
  -q, --quiet            Do not output any message
<snip>
```

There's the option. `-c, --config`.

And now let's look at 2.2.1:

```
$ php ./codecept.phar help build
Usage:
  build

Options:
  -h, --help            Display this help message
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
<snip>
```

Hey! There is no longer a `-c` option.

What can I do to point `codecept` at the config directory?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3173
Something is wrong with phar files of 2.2.1 version, I can only recommend to use Codeception installed with composer until that issue is fixed.

Comment: This is good advice. OP is using `wget`, which is not ideal for version locking. I would add to this that OP should version lock in Composer for the time being (https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions). Edit: OP could `wget` the specific version of Codeception they want to use, but that is the Wrong Way for handling dependencies.

Comment: I have heard that the issue was fixed, please download the phar file again and try to run tests again.